# How to start nginx via different port(other than 80)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Hi I am a newbie on nginx, I tried to set it up on my server (running Ubuntu 4),  which already has apache running.

So after I `apt-get install` it, I tried to start nginx. Then I get the message like this:

```
Starting nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

That makes sense as Apache is using port 80.

Then I tried to modify `nginx.conf`, I reference some articles, so I changed it like so:

```
   server {

        listen       8080;

        location / {
         proxy_pass  http://94.143.9.34:9500;
         proxy_set_header   Host             $host:8080;
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Via    "nginx";
        }
```

After saving this and try to start nginx again,  I still get the same error as previously.  I cannot really find a related post about this, could any good people shred some light?

**I should post all the content in conf here:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

   server {

        listen       81;

        location / {
         proxy_pass  http://94.143.9.34:9500;
         proxy_set_header   Host             $host:81;
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Via    "nginx";
        }


    }
}

 mail {
      # See sample authentication script at:
      # http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript

      auth_http localhost/auth.php;
      pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
      imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";

     server {
         listen     localhost:110;
         protocol   pop3;
         proxy      on;
     }

     server {
         listen     localhost:143;
         protocol   imap;
         proxy      on;
     }
 }
```

Basically,  I changed nothing except adding the server part.

Comment: Is this your complete config? If not, please post the complete configuration. Are you sure no other process is listening on port 8080?

Comment: As Khaled requested, I post all the content in the conf file,

Comment: Please, post the output of `sudo netstat -lnp | grep 80`.

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13731/apache2

Comment: You can refer to my post
[Using Port Other than 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095466/nginx-not-routing-to-the-net-core-project-with-port-other-than-80)

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you've left the default server configuration in the `sites_enabled` folder.

The file in question has a bunch of commented out lines, but not all are - the default configuration is tangled among them. I suggest you remove the whole file (or the first part if all your configurations are in the same file).

However, if you can't find it there, I suggest you do a search for 80. It's bound to be in the nginx configuration files somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I am using VMWare and had the same errors.

I removed my default config for the sites_enabled but also removed :

```
listen   [::]:80
```

...from my config files (previously needed for MacPorts). I'm not sure which port VMWare listens on but it didn't like 80!